# ASP .NET Core Generated Swagger Descriptions missing on object attributes

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am attempting to generate swagger json from an API that I am building with ASP Net Core 3.1 and Swashbuckle SwaggerGen. I'm using the below in my Startup.cs in order to generate documentation based on summaries of methods and models.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen( options =>
            {
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly( ).GetName( ).Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine( AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile );
                options.IncludeXmlComments( xmlPath );
            } );
```

This does work in most instances. But it does not work with custom objects. Take these two attributes for example:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// ExampleValue description.
        /// </summary>
        public string ExampleValue{ get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// ExampleValue2 description.
        /// </summary>
        public CustomObject ExampleValue2{ get; set; }
```

In the generated json, you can see the description does not show up for ExampleValue2

```
          "exampleValue": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "ExampleValue description.",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "exampleValue2": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CustomObject"
          },
```

To my understanding, if I put a summary on top of the CustomObject that will show up for all references of the object but that's not what I would expect here. If I use this custom object in lots of places, I would like to have unique descriptions for each instance of it in any of my models that are used for requests.

When I look at the .xml file of the assembly the summary is indeed there on the CustomObject so I do not believe it is a problem with the assembly file.

Comment: OK, I deleted my answer, hopefully there will be an answer that works for you. BR